# In excel VBA create multidimensional dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort through a couple hundred rows in a workbook to pull information based on progressive keys. First, create a list of all unique names, then for each unique name find all associated product codes, and finally create a list of each quantity of product. What it should look like:

```
'Name1
'-----product1
'-------------quantity1
'-------------quantity2
'-----product2
'-------------quantity1
'-------------quantity2
'name2
'-----product1
'-------------quantity1
'-------------quantity2
'-----product2
'-------------quantity1
'-------------quantity2
```

I tried using a dictionary but can't figure out how to get it to return more than the first entry per unique name. This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CreateNameList2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Label-Mod Data")

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Dim AssociateName As String
Dim ColAssociateNames As Integer
Dim ColCurrentLabels As Integer
Dim ColPTSCodes As Integer
Dim ColRegionCodes As Integer
Dim nbRows As Long
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Variant

ColAssociateNames = 8
ColCurrentLabels = 9
ColPTSCodes = 14
ColRegionCodes = 15
nbRows = 155
i = 2
    
    For iRow = 2 To nbRows
 
        AssociateName = sws.Cells(iRow, ColAssociateNames).Value2
 

        If Not dict.Exists(AssociateName) Then
             
        dict.Add Key:=AssociateName, Item:=Array(sws.Cells(i, ColPTSCodes).Value2, sws.Cells(i, ColCurrentLabels).Value2, sws.Cells(i, ColRegionCodes).Value2)
        i = i + 1
         
        End If
 
    Next iRow
      
    iRow = 2
    
    For Each k In dict.Keys
 
        With sws
             .Cells(iRow, 18).Value2 = k
             .Cells(iRow, 19).Value2 = dict.Item(k)(0) 
             .Cells(iRow, 20).Value2 = dict.Item(k)(1) 
             .Cells(iRow, 21).Value2 = dict.Item(k)(2) 
        End With
 
        iRow = iRow + 1
 
    Next k
  
    Set dict = Nothing

Debug.Print

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Can this be done with a dictionary?

For privacy reasons I can't show the data but I will try to explain it.
My raw data comes in 3 columns and varies in number of rows, todays is 155. Column 1 has a name, column 2 has a product ID and column 3 has a quantity. There are currently 48 possible names, 12 possible product ID's and undetermined quantity amounts. Looks Like this:

```
Name1  |  product 3  |  25
Name1  |  product 1  |  12
Name5  |  product 9  |  171
Name4  |  product 3  |  48
Name1  |  product 7  |  23
Name42 |  product 9  |  9
Name5  |  product 1  |  22
Name4  |  product 3  |  42
```

What I need to do is change it to:

```
Name1  |  product 1  |  12
       |  product 3  |  25
       |  product 7  |  23
Name4  |  product 3  |  90
(combine above quantity with matching name and product)  
Name5  |  product 1  |  22
       |  product 9  |  171
Name42 |  product 9  |  9
```

Comment: You can use a top-level dictionary keyed on "Name" - each entry is a dictionary keyed on "Product", and each entry in the Product dictionary is a Collection of Quantities ?  A little difficult without seeing your actual data (your code doesn't seem to match your example hierarchy)

Comment: I would probably use a collection of [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement) declarations to solve this. Create a type of [name, product, count] then iterate through your list. If it finds an existing node with matching name/product then increment count otherwise add new node with count 1.

Comment: I have edited the question above to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Like this would work:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim dict As Object, rw As Range, Q, kN, kP
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set rw = Range("A1:C1")               'first row of data
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) = 3   'while row data is complete
        kN = rw.Cells(1).Value            'name key
        kP = rw.Cells(2).Value            'product key
        Q = rw.Cells(3).Value             'quantity
        'add keys if missing...
        If Not dict.exists(kN) Then dict.Add kN, CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        If Not dict(kN).exists(kP) Then dict(kN).Add kP, 0
        dict(kN)(kP) = dict(kN)(kP) + Q    'sum quantity for this key combination
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1)              'next row
    Loop
    
    'output to Immediate pane
    For Each kN In dict
        Debug.Print "---" & kN & "---"
        For Each kP In dict(kN)
            Debug.Print "   " & kP & " = " & dict(kN)(kP)
        Next
    Next kN
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information provided, it looks like you can make use of a composite key comprised of the Name and Product identifiers.  Doing so can support a solution that uses an AssociateName-to-nameProductQuantityMap `Dictionary` where nameProductQuantityMap is also a `Dictionary` that associates Quantity totals to each Name + Product composite key.

```
Option Explicit

'May need a more elaborate delimiter if "." used in the Names or Products
Const compositeKeyDelimiter As String = "."

Private Type TColumns
    Associate As Long
    Name As Long
    Product As Long
    Quantity As Long
End Type

Sub CreateNameList2Answer()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Label-Mod Data")
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim AssociateName As String
    Dim ColAssociateNames As Integer
    Dim ColCurrentLabels As Integer
    Dim ColPTSCodes As Integer
    Dim ColRegionCodes As Integer
    Dim nbRows As Long
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ColAssociateNames = 8
    ColCurrentLabels = 9
    ColPTSCodes = 14
    ColRegionCodes = 15
    nbRows = 155
    i = 2
    
    'Modify if these are not mapped to the correct column names
    Dim xColumns As TColumns
    xColumns.Associate = ColAssociateNames
    xColumns.Name = ColCurrentLabels
    xColumns.Product = ColPTSCodes
    xColumns.Quantity = ColRegionCodes
    
    Dim xAssociateName As Variant
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xProduct As String
    Dim xQuantity As Long
    
    Dim xCompositeKey As String
    Dim nameProductQuantityMap As Object
    For iRow = 2 To nbRows
 
        AssociateName = sws.Cells(iRow, xColumns.Associate).Value2
        
        xName = sws.Cells(i, xColumns.Name).Value2
        xProduct = sws.Cells(i, xColumns.Product).Value2
        xQuantity = CLng(sws.Cells(i, xColumns.Quantity).Value2)
        
        xCompositeKey = CreateCompositeKey(xName, xProduct)
        
        If Not dict.Exists(AssociateName) Then
            dict.Add Key:=AssociateName, Item:=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        
        Set nameProductQuantityMap = dict.Item(AssociateName)
        
        If Not nameProductQuantityMap.Exists(xCompositeKey) Then
            nameProductQuantityMap.Add xCompositeKey, 0
        End If
        
        nameProductQuantityMap.Item(xCompositeKey) _
            = nameProductQuantityMap.Item(xCompositeKey) + xQuantity
                     
        i = i + 1
 
    Next iRow
      
    iRow = 2
    
    Dim xKey As Variant
    
    For Each xAssociateName In dict.Keys
        Set nameProductQuantityMap = dict.Item(xAssociateName)
        For Each xKey In nameProductQuantityMap
        
            LoadContent sws, iRow, CStr(xAssociateName), _
                CStr(xKey), _
                nameProductQuantityMap.Item(xKey)
                
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next
    Next xAssociateName
  
    Set dict = Nothing
    Set nameProductQuantityMap = Nothing

Debug.Print

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub LoadContent(ByVal pWksht As Worksheet, ByVal pRow As Long, _
    ByVal pAssociate As String, _
    ByVal pCompositeKey As String, _
    ByVal pQuantity As Long)
    
    Dim xName As String
    Dim xProduct As String
    
    ExtractNameAndProductFromKey pCompositeKey, xName, xProduct
    
    With pWksht
        .Cells(pRow, 18).Value2 = pAssociate
        .Cells(pRow, 19).Value2 = xName
        .Cells(pRow, 20).Value2 = xProduct
        .Cells(pRow, 21).Value2 = pQuantity
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CreateCompositeKey(ByVal pName As String, ByVal pProduct As String) As String
    CreateCompositeKey = pName & compositeKeyDelimiter & pProduct
End Function

Private Sub ExtractNameAndProductFromKey(ByVal pCompositeKey As String, ByRef pOutName As String, ByRef pOutProduct As String)
    Dim xKeyParts As Variant
    xKeyParts = Split(pCompositeKey, compositeKeyDelimiter)
    
    pOutName = xKeyParts(0)
    pOutProduct = xKeyParts(1)
End Sub
```